# Get the address of a matrix in GLM library

Tags: c++, opengl, glm

Is there a way to get the address of a matrix from a GLM matrix?

I'm using opengl 4 and glm library though I can't seem to find anything, which might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the memory of any glm type by using [glm::value_ptr](http://glm.g-truc.net/api-0.9.4/a00158.html#ga140f5c39d519780c61e02e47daa7d18a).
Matrix types store their values in column-major order, and as floats.

Comment: thank you, is there any web reference for glm library?

Comment: @OlegBondarenko the link in my answer should take you to the documentation. If not: http://glm.g-truc.net/api-0.9.4/modules.html